# 404 Error - AWS EC2

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

When I try to open my instance via the Public DNS, I get a 404 error.

However, in my security group, I have HTTP/HTTPS/SSH configured to allow all incoming requests. When I connect to the instance via SSH, I can see all of my files there from my repo.

I am running on an Ubuntu 64-bit server with Nginx and Gunicorn.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There could be many things going on here, is your server running? Are you using the correct port? Is your instance in the public subnet (attached to an internet gateway?)

Comment: @DanielEsponda I'm using a Postgres database from RDS on Django, and yes I do have those settings correct. Additionally, I have my allowed hosts open to all (for the time being).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities for getting 404 file not found error

1. Make sure /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html is found or not.
2. check with nginx.conf file, if it is directing to index.html or not.